# Why doesn't this django code work?

Tags: django, reverse, keyword-argument

urls.py

```
url(r'^some/page/$', views.some_page,
    {'template_name': 'some/page.html'},
    name='some_page'),
```

views.py

```
url = request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('some_page')).lower()
response = HttpResponseRedirect(url)
return response
```

Question:
Why doesn't this code work?

```
url = request.build_absolute_uri(reverse('some_page', 
    kwargs={"template_name": "another/page.html"})).lower()
```

I'm using django 1.2 on google appengine. Since I get the same error for any kind of typo/mistake, I didn't think it was useful to paste that error message here.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because [reverse](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#reverse) expects the arguments to “fill in” regular expressions in the url. So `reverse('some_page')` should work.

What do you expect it to do?

Comment: I wanted to redirect to another view with a custom template name. How can I do it?